# What is the difference between Spin and Spin Duplicates?

Tags: modeling

In Blender 2.81 there are spin tools. The first one is Spin tool and the other is Spin Duplicates. I used both of them and didn't see any difference. What is the difference? If you know the answer please share with me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

*Spin* tools creates a revolution surface from the selected geometry, while the *Spin Duplicate* operator creates a circular duplication kind of "polar array" of the selection.

[image]

Current issue I see is that apparently using the tools from the toolbar doesn't seem to automatically set the correct operator preferences, making them by default behave the same unless you manually untick the *Duplicate* option which seems like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this one is a bug too. Both Spin and Spin Duplicates have use duplicate option. How can I call Spin Duplicate operator then? (Not from toolbar)

Comment: Spacebar menu, like all operators, otherwise create a dedicated hotkey