# How to wrap a face around a cylinder

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

I am relatively new to Blender, I use it to create 3D models for work.

I have this problem often and I can never figure it out.

I am trying to wrap the highlited face's around the cylinder to create a hinge.

I could use another object and mash them togheter but I feel like there should be an easier way.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: I think the problem stems from the fact that you are thinking about how the object is built in real life (which can help some times), rather than how to model it with polygons. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-a-90-joint/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66733/how-would-i-smooth-a-90-degree-pipe-angle/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161454/what-is-the-difference-between-spin-and-spin-duplicates

Comment: why don't you just use a cylinder instead of your plane?

Comment: As @DuarteFarrajotaRamos shows with his links, you have to build geometry that resembles the curving. You cannot simply bend it around like you would in the real world. And even though there are tools like _Simple Deform_ modifier for example which could achieve this, not only would it perhaps take longer to get the settings correct so that it fits, it also can't work with a large face with no subdivisions. The modifier works along edges and vertices, but you only have them on the corners, none inbetween to bend along.